# react-redux-firebase, "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, frontend

I am working on a project that integrates react, redux, and firebase. react-redux-firebase seems to be a convenient tool. However, the code is not being complied successfully. Below is the error, webpack.config.js, .babelrc, and index.js. Thanks for help in advance.

Error message:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-redux-firebase/src/connect.js 
Module parse failed: 
/Users/xiqianglin/ucsdflyers/node_modules/react-redux-firebase/src/connect.js 
Unexpected token (43:24) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. 
|     }
| 
|     static contextTypes = {
|       store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
|     };
@ ./~/react-redux-firebase/src/index.js 1:0-31  @ ./src/index.js  @ multi ./src/index.js


/****And there are other similar errors, all "...appropriate loader..." ***/
```

webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
entry: [
      './src/index.js'
        ],

module: {
      loaders: [
                  {test: /\.js$/,
                   exclude: /node_modules/,
                   loader:'babel-loader'}
                ]
        },

resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".es6"]
},

output: {
      filename: "index_bundle.js",
      path: __dirname + '/dist'
        },

plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

index.js

```
/*Other Imports...*/
import { firebaseStateReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'; //This is the line causing error

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  documeng.getElementById('app')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Duble check that you `npm install`-ed all your dependencies.

Then if that doesn't work, try this:

`npm install babel-preset-es2015`

and add the a query for es2015 after your `exclude`

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader:'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: ['es2015']
  }
}
```

If you need to include a specific node module, try including your source directory and that specific node module folder to be parsed by babel-loader.
So instead of the `exclude: /node_modules/,` try

```
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-redux-firebase")
  ]
```

Comment: I have both 'es2015' and 'react' on .babelrc. And I also did as you suggested, and error persists

Comment: I updated my answer with another thing you can try. I may be that you need to include your `react-redux-firebase`  rather than exclude all of your node_modules folder.

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up comments. Unfortunately, I tried and still the error persists.

Comment: What version of react-redux-firebase and webpack are you using? Have you tried using the config from the example?